# YEAR function is not Working in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

Not able to use YEAR() in symfony 2 doctrine..My code is given below

```
   $users = $this->getEntityManager()
               ->createQuery("SELECT YEAR(u.dob) from AcmeDemoBundle:AppUsers u")
               ->getResult();
```

While running this code,it shows the following error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'YEAR'

Why this happen ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping for this function (and many others for managing datetime elements) does not exist in doctrine.
You've to use [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) and add the following mapping to your configuration,

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

You can also map it to a function of your own with a bit of more work.

Comment: Thank u for your response @ahmed ..there is detaled description regarding Doctrine Extensions...anyway i will try on that way..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add custom function to doctrine for example:

```
<?php
namespace Project\CustomBundle\Dql;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

class YearFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    private $arg;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf('YEAR(%s)', $this->arg->dispatch($sqlWalker));
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->arg = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

in config.yml doctrine section

```
#config.yml

doctrine:
  orm:
    ...
    dql:
      datetime_functions:
        year: Project\CustomBundle\DqlYearFunction
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that DoctrineExtensions has Year and other functions, so @Ahmed answer is more accurate, but I'll leave it as example of simple method to add custom functions to Doctrine

Comment: Thank u for your answer @waldek_c... I tried ur code...But did not show anything...anyway thanking u again for your response..